# Error al compilar un proyecto Maven. There are no JREs installed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

He descargado un proyecto en sourceforge y al importarlo para empezar a editarlo me da muchos errores entre los cuales esta uno que dice "**Java Build  Path Problems**" en la consola al escribir el comando "java -version" me muestra "**java version 1.8.0_92**"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pd. Utilizo la IDE de Eclipse en Windows 64 Bits. 
Pd2. El proyecto es un Maven Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta esto:

- Click derecho sobre el projecto.
- Menu Propiedades (Properties)
- Busca "Java build path", luego "Libraries"
- Elimina "JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6]"
- Clickea en "Add Library" luego "JRE System Library"
- Selecciona nuevo "Execution Environment" (o usa "Workspace default JRE")

Comment: perfecto!!! CRACK!!